# Navigate between detail views of a table view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

So I have a UITableView that navigates to a detail view when a cell is selected. Each cell and it's detail view passes through different data depending on which cell is selected. On the storyboard it is one generic detail view with a text label and an image view that loads in data from an array.

What I want to do is navigate from the current detail view to the next detail view (for the next item in the table) without having to go back to the main table view controller. How can I do this? I would like to do this with a button.

I have looked at this but I can't seem to get it right/not sure it's exactly the same thing: [Navigate between sibling detail views of a parent table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377994/navigate-between-sibling-detail-views-of-a-parent-table-view)

Comment: Do you want to add the next detail view on to the navigation stack (assuming this is within a UINavigationController) on top of the current detail view? Or have, for example, the "Back" button, go from the "next detail view" back to the tableview (not recommended).

Comment: Also, how would a user indicate that they want to navigate to next item? You'll need some sort of IBAction, button, or gesture that would indicate that the user wants to go to the next detail view.

Comment: Yes I'd like to add the next detail view on to the navigation stack if that's the best way to do it @benhameen And yes they would navigate with the use of a button

Comment: okay, what data is needed for the detail view to be initiated? Essentially, say the data for your tableview is held in an array. You'll need to pass that array to the detail view and along to each detail view in order to be able to navigate between them. And you'd init them in the same way you pushed the first detail view on the stack.